# Sum of convex and concave functions when one is greater than the other

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given two $C^\infty$ functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>g(x)\text{ }\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, we know that $f(x)$ is convex while $g(x)$ is concave. Now, let's define $F(x)\equiv f(x)+g(x)$.

> Excluding the case in which $f(x)+g(x)$ sum up to a linear function, is it possible to say that $F(x)$ is convex?
>
> What happens if, for instance, $f(x)$ is decreasing and convex and $g(x)$ is increasing and concave?

Comment: $f=\exp$, $g=-2\exp$

Comment: Let $f = -{1 \over 2} g$ for any strictly negative concave $g$.

Comment: why is it excluded that $F(x)$ is linear? Isn't a linear function trivially convex (versus strictly convex)? also what does "one is greater than the other" in the title refer to?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! Probably the question should be deleted since it's possible to provide many easy counterexamples. However, if I take $f(x)=4-x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$ the plot of their sum is convex in the restriction of the domain of $g(x)$ where $x^3$ is greater than $4-x^2$. Is there a way to generalize such a lucky event?

Comment: Sure. You can add, say, $ax^2$ to many continuous functions for sufficiently large $a$ and "make" it convex. You just need a bounded second derivative